# Ошибка входа при разных полях Email и UserName

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2

Есть стандартная таблица пользователей фреймворка Identity 2.2.1, ничего не изменялось. В этой таблице есть 2 поля: `Email` и `UserName`. После регистрации пользователя поле `UserName` заполняется тем же, что указано в `Email`.

Добавил возможность менять Email и UserName, просто чтобы не дублировалось и для красоты, вроде как уникальным должен быть только Email адрес. Но при попытки войти, аккаунт, у которого эти два поля отличаются, получает `result == SignInStatus.Failure`:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там, где поля одинаковые проблем нет. Как это исправить?

Comment: А PasswordSignInAsync первым аргументом может принимать email?

Comment: Я тут ничего не менял, это все VS добавила при создании проекта с Identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю вся проблема в том, что метод должен принимать username,  в качестве первого аргумента [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt173779(v=vs.108).aspx)

И пока username=email  все работает, но как только меняешь перестаёт